# What formula or Script to use to automate Shifting cells to Right or/and Left and Cut and Paste wrong column content to correct column google sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

My table (~70k rows) has data in columns/rows out of order as so:

| ID | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | PLACE | PROBLEMS TO FIX |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID: 0 | Last Name: Williams | First Name: Tracie | Place: US | CORRECT DATA |
| ID: 1 Last Name: Gregory | First Name: Eric | Place: US |  | ID & FIRST NAME COMBINED CELL |
| ID: 2 | Last Name: Buchanan | Place: UK |  | MISSING FIRST NAME IN COLUMN C |
| ID: 3 | Place: UK |  |  | MISSING LAST NAME IN COLUMN B |
| ID: 4 |  | Last Name: Cormick | Place: UK | LAST NAME IN WRONG COLUMN (FIRSTNAME) |

Issues Screenshot:

[image: Issues Screenshot]

Here is the expected result I got by applying the manual steps in the **"FIXES"** Column / D column:

| ID | LASTNAME | FIRSTNAME | PLACE | FIXES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ID: 0 | Last Name: Williams | First Name: Tracie | Place: US | CORRECT DATA (NO FIXES) |
| ID: 1 | Last Name: Gregory | First Name: Eric | Place: US | B3: INSERT CELL AND SHIFT TO RIGHT 1 CELL A3: CUT CELL A2 FROM "LAST" TO END OF CELL A3 B3: PASTE FROM "LAST" TO END OF CELL A3 INTO CELL B3 A3: IN CELL A3, DELETE FROM "LAST" TO END OF CELL A3 |
| ID: 2 | Last Name: Buchanan |  | Place: UK | C4: INSERT CELL AND SHIFT TO RIGHT 1 CELL |
| ID: 3 |  |  | Place: UK | B5: INSERT CELL AND SHIFT TO RIGHT 2 CELLS |
| ID: 4 | Last Name: Cormick |  | Place: UK | B6: DELETE CELL AND SHIFT TO THE LEFT 1 CELL C6: INSERT CELL AND SHIFT TO RIGHT 1 CELL |

Fixes Screenshot:

[image: Fixes Screenshot]

The manual fixes work fine but it is very time consuming.

## **1st alternative to manual solution:**

As a first alternative solution I thought of maybe recording macros, then calling those macros in a Google sheet formula.

I have something like following pull-down formula (with pre-recorded macros as value_if_true variable) in mind (in Column B, and similar on for the other columns):

```
=IFS(
    REGEXMATCH(B1, "First Name:"), CALLMACROSHIFTRIGHTONECELL,
    REGEXMATCH(B1, "ID:"), CALLMACROSHIFTLEFTONECELL,
    REGEXMATCH(B1, "Place:"), CALLMACROSHIFTRIGHTTWOCELLS
    REGEXMATCH(B1, "Last Name"), "",
    TRUE, "")
```

But I'm not sure if that's possible and couldn't find any documentation on calling macros in Google Sheets formulas.

## **2nd alternative to manual solution:**

If there's no way to perform the 1st alternative currently in google Sheets, I thought next of using a script by calling the Fixes steps in Google Apps Script Functions.

But I can't find the documentation about **INSERTING CELL AND SHIFT TO RIGHT** command:

[image: Insert_Cell_and_Shift_Right]

or **DELETING CELL AND SHIFT TO LEFT** command:

[image: Delete_Cell_and_Shift_Left]

and **CUTTING A CELL PORTION AND PASTING IT IN ADJACENT CELL**:

[image: Cut_Portion_of_Cell]

If you know of a more efficient way to achieve the expectd result (known script or techniques) or if you know references to the needed Google Apps Script documentation, I'll be very grateful if you'd like to share it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's useful, you can create a formula that will "accomodate" the data in other columns if it is as "standard" the labels as your example:

```
=BYROW(A2:D,LAMBDA(each,LAMBDA(r,IFNA({
  "ID: "&REGEXEXTRACT(r,"ID: (.+?) [Last|First|Place]"),
  "Last Name: "&REGEXEXTRACT(r,"Last Name: (.+?) [First|Place]"),
  "First Name: "&REGEXEXTRACT(r,"First Name: (.+?) [Place]"),
  "Place: "&REGEXEXTRACT(r,"Place: (.+)")
}))(TEXTJOIN("  ",1,each))))
```

[image]

Comment: I understand it's 70 k rows, but if it runs and the data is static, you can then copy only values and delete the formula

Comment: Thanks for the ideas and tips. I'll test now and be back asa with result for big dataset.

Comment: Amazingly good solution! Thanks again. Be well!

Comment: Very useful, saved me hours, glad I asked, was worth it! Made me curious to see how to get the similar result with `REGEXREPLACE` instead. After a few trying hours I got the solution below, though yours is shorter and more to the point. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity and to train the concept I tweaked @Martin 's amazing answer to be used with `REGEXREPLACE` as so (though Martin's simpler and prefered one) :

```
=BYROW(A2:D6,LAMBDA(each,LAMBDA(r,IFNA({
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "Last Name.+?$|First Name.+?$|Place.+?$",""),
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "ID.+Last Name:?|First Name.+?$|ID.+Place.+?$|Place.+?$",""),
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "ID.+First Name:?|ID.+Place.+?$|Place.+?$",""),
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "ID.+Place:+?","")
}))(TEXTJOIN("  ",1,each))))
```

[image: regexreplace solution 1]

or

```
=BYROW(A2:D6,LAMBDA(each,LAMBDA(r,IFNA({
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "Last Name.+?$|First Name.+?$|Place.+?$",""),
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "^.+Last Name:?|First Name.+?$|^.+Place.+?$|Place.+?$",""),
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "^.+First Name:?|^.+Place.+?$|Place.+?$",""),
  REGEXREPLACE(r, "^.+Place:+?","")
}))(TEXTJOIN("  ",1,each))))
```

[image: regexreplace solution 2]